# Crosstab Query with Dynamic Columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

I'm having trouble with a Cross Tab query in SQL Server and was hoping that someone could please help?

I have the following table:

```
- Student ID - Name - Course     - Course Level -
- 1          - John - English    - E2 -
- 1          - John - Mathns     - E3 -
- 1          - John - Computing  - L2 -
```

Each learner has to sit an English, Maths and Computing Assessment and a level is given.

I need to report what one learner achieved in each assessment on one line like the following:

```
- StudentID - Name - English - Maths - Computing - 
- 1         - John - E2      - E3    - L2 -
```

I have been given this code from the comments below: Thank you @iamdave.

```
SELECT PERSON_CODE, [Computing], [Maths], [English]
FROM TT
PIVOT (MAX(LEVEL) FOR COURSE_CODE IN ([DL], [NUM15], [ENG15])) AS P
```

I just need to add a group by so that John only appears as one row as I am currently seeing this:

```
- StudentID - Name - English - Maths - Computing - 
- 1         - John - E2      - E3    - L2 -
- 1         - John - E2      - E3    - L2 -
- 1         - John - E2      - E3    - L2 -
```

Instead of:

```
- StudentID - Name - English - Maths - Computing - 
- 1         - John - E2      - E3    - L2 -
- 2         - Amy  - L1      - L2    - E3 -
```

Thank you

Comment: Your table columns are inconsistent with the query. Correct it first

Comment: Sorry I should explain that StudentID and Person_Code are the same fields. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you will need to get the results in your question is:

```
create table StudentResults(StudentID int,Name nvarchar(50),Course nvarchar(50), CourseLevel nvarchar(10));
insert into StudentResults values(1,'John','English','E2'),(1,'John','Maths','E3'),(1,'John','Computing','L2');

select StudentID
        ,Name
        ,[Computing]
        ,[Maths]
        ,[English]
from StudentResults
pivot(max(CourseLevel) for Course in([Computing],[Maths],[English])
     ) as p;
```

Output:

```
StudentID   Name    Computing   Maths   English
1           John    L2          E3      E2
```

Though as you may be able to work out, this requires hard coding the subjects.  If your list of subjects is likely to change, then this query will no longer be fit for purpose.

If you are comfortable, you can remedy this with dynamic SQL:

```
declare @cols as  nvarchar(max)
       ,@query as nvarchar(max);

set @cols = stuff(
                   (select distinct ','+quotename(Course)
                    from StudentResults
                    for xml path(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'
                   )
                 ,1,1,''
                 );

set @query = 'select StudentID
                    ,Name
                    ,'+@cols+'
            from StudentResults
            pivot (max(CourseLevel) for Course in ('+@cols+')
                  ) p';

execute (@query);
```

Ideally though, you would simply return a set of data, as it appears to be in your source table and let your reporting layer (SSRS for example) handle the pivoting, which it is much better suited towards than pure SQL.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me. It has worked to pivot the courses but I still have a list of duplicate rows for each learner rather John only showing once.

Comment: @MikeWatkins  Based on your test data these queries work.  You cannot provide a non-representative data set and expect the solutions provided here to work elsewhere.  Please update your question to show a representative sample of the data you are working with.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I am new to the site. To explain further I have a table where the StudentID can be duplicated depending on how many times that a student has completed the test. You have fixed the issue of pivoting the courses for me but this is what I still see instead of one line: PERSON_CODE DL                  NUM15   ENG15
39310          NULL                    e2    NULL
39310          NULL                   NULL      e3
39310                 e2                    NULL    NULL

Comment: @MikeWatkins  Please update your question with these details, as well as the supporting data.  It would also help if you could include any other columns that differentiate the results returned, such as a test date.  With these new fields you will also need to update your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT studentId,
StudentName,
English,
Maths,
Computing
FROM (
SELECT T.StudentId,
    T.StudentName,
    T.Course,
    T.CourseLevel
FROM Test T
) AS J
PIVOT(MAX(CourseLevel) FOR Course IN (
        [English],
        [Maths],
        [Computing]
        )) AS P
```