# How to dynamically convert rows to columns in sql

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table as follows.

```
TagName Value Datetime
--------------------------
  T1     v1      D1
  T2     v2      D1
  T3     v3      D1
  T1     v4      D2
  T2     v5      D2
   T3     v6      D2
```

and I want to create a select query that returns the following

```
T1    T2    T3    Datetime
----------------------------
v1    v2    v3       d1
V4    v5    v6       d2
```

The T1/T2/T3 is dynamic i.e there can be any number of tags. I have the database that records the value of different tags at particular timestamp. I want the values of all the tags at one timestamp in one row. Would anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Did you search for dynamic cross tab for SQL server on this site or google?  Here's 1 of many results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935934/crosstab-query-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(TagName) From Yourtable  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select ' + @SQL + ',[DateTime]
From  YourTable
Pivot (max([Value]) For [TagName] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

```
T1  T2  T3  DateTime
v1  v2  v3  D1
v4  v5  v6  D2
```